# Replace function only works once (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I need to replace a string (str1) with another string (str2) every time str1 shows in a specific div.

This is what I got so far

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function(){

var str=document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML; 
var n=str.replace("Google","Yahoo");
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML=n;

}); 

</script>
```

and the html

```
<div id="foo">
Google is the best website ever <br />
Google is not the best website ever</div>
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, it only replaces the first instance of the word Google.

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to add to make it replace ALL the instances of the word?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing all occurrences of a string in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/replacing-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use regex `/string/g` to replace all occurrences, you are using substring which will replace only first occurances as per documentation of [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y3RDu/)**

```
var n=str.replace(/Google/g,"Yahoo");
```

[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
The replace() method returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement. The pattern can be a string or a RegExp, and the replacement can be a string or a function to be called for each match.

> str.replace(regexp|substr, newSubStr|function)

You are using substr pattern which will replace first occurance only.

**substr (pattern)**

> A String that is to be replaced by newSubStr. It is treated as a
>   verbatim string and is not interpreted as a regular expression. Only
>   the first occurrence will be replaced.

Use this regexp patter to replace all occurances.

**regexp (pattern)**

> A RegExp object or literal. The match is replaced by
>   the return value of parameter #2.

Comment: good answer. can you explain why the `replace()` function, when given a string argument, is not replacing every occurrence?

Comment: Thanks, please check my updated answer, I hope it will answer you question.